# How can I get connection pool metrics in Cassandra ..?

Tags: java, cassandra

Is there any way to get connection pool metrics in Cassandra using CqlSession. Need answer specific to core java.

I want to get each client connection metrics in **Cassandra version(4.9.0).**

Metrics like -> opened connection, closed connection, active connections ..

And

Is there any way to notify evetime when new connection is created or update..?

Answer (score 0):

In 4.x versions, you need to explicitly enable in configuration file every metric that you need - something like this (taken from [docs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.9/manual/core/metrics/), full list of metrics is in the [reference](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.9/manual/core/configuration/reference/)):

```
datastax-java-driver.advanced.metrics {
  session.enabled = [ connected-nodes, cql-requests ]
  node.enabled = [ pool.open-connections, pool.in-flight ]
}
```

Regarding the hook on the opened/closed connection, I'm not sure that there is an easy way to do that, except just record previous numbers of the opened connections.  Maybe such things would be easier to track via Prometheus, or other monitoring system.  Here is [an example](https://github.com/DataStax-Examples/metrics-to-prometheus-java) of how you can integrate driver metrics with Prometheus.

Comment: Whether it will give me each client specific or database level..

Comment: these metrics are on the client side.